# typeMismatch. Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead

Tags: json, swift

I cannot find an answer to this problem. I'm trying to parse a JSON response which contains an array of elements. This is what I'm doing to get the data from the endpoint:

```
func getCarruseles(completion: @escaping (Result<[CarruselesData], Error>)-> Void) {
        
        let urlString =  baseUrl + "url"
        
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            completion(.failure(NetworkingError.badUrl))
            return
        }
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.setValue("Bearer token", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        
        let session = URLSession.shared

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                if let unwrappedError = error {
                    completion(.failure(unwrappedError))
                    return
                }

                if let unwrappedData = data {
                    do{
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: unwrappedData, options: [])
                        if let successRes = try? JSONDecoder().decode([CarruselesData].self, from: unwrappedData){
                            completion(.success(successRes))
                        }else{

                            let errorResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(CarruselesErrorResponse.self, from: unwrappedData)
                            print("Error \(errorResponse)")
                            completion(.failure(errorResponse))
                        }
                    }catch{
                        completion(.failure(error))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

This is the structure I'm using to parse the data:

```
struct CarruselesData: Codable {
    let title: String
    let type: String
    let items: [Carrusel]
}

struct Carrusel: Codable {
    let title: String
    let imageUrl: String
    let videoUrl: String
    let description: String
}
```

And this is the response I'm getting:

```
(
        {
        items =         (
                        {
                description = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";
                imageUrl = "http://placeimg.com/640/480/any";
                title = "Movie 1";
                videoUrl = "https://d11gqohmu80ljn.cloudfront.net/128/media-20210712191955-cbdi-0.m3u8/master.m3u8";
            },
                        {
                description = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";
                imageUrl = "http://placeimg.com/640/480/any";
                title = "Movie 2";
                videoUrl = "https://d11gqohmu80ljn.cloudfront.net/128/media-20210712191955-cbdi-0.m3u8/master.m3u8";
            },
                        {
                description = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";
                imageUrl = "http://placeimg.com/640/480/any";
                title = "Movie 3";
            },
                        {
                description = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";
                imageUrl = "http://placeimg.com/640/480/any";
                title = "Movie 4";
                videoUrl = "https://d11gqohmu80ljn.cloudfront.net/128/media-20210712191955-cbdi-0.m3u8/master.m3u8";
            }
        );
        title = "Carousel Thumb";
        type = thumb;
    },
        {
        items =         (
                        {
                description = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";
                imageUrl = "http://placeimg.com/320/480/any";
                title = "Movie 1";
                videoUrl = "https://d11gqohmu80ljn.cloudfront.net/128/media-20210712191955-cbdi-0.m3u8/master.m3u8";
            },
                        {
                description = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";
                imageUrl = "http://placeimg.com/320/480/any";
                title = "Movie 2";
            }
        );
        title = "Carousel Poster";
        type = poster;
    }
)
```

This is the error Im getting: typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that, inside the items array not all of the items contains a "videoURL". To solve that, I just had to put the videoUrl parameter of the Carrusel structure as Optional like this:

```
struct Carrusel: Codable {
    let title: String
    let imageUrl: String
    let videoUrl: String?
    let description: String
}
```